# in Selenium IDE btnUpdate not found this is a development (code) issue

Tags: selenium-ide

Actually i am not understanding what is the real issue because manually all functionality proper run but selenium IDE give the error.

> Click  :  id=ctl00_Dialogproxy_createnode_btnUpdate

Steps to Reproduce the error :

1. Click on create node button image.
2. Click on save button.

Result :

1. Create node pop up window should be open.
2. Give the error.

Pop up window display but after click event give the error

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error Display a Log table in Selenium IDE : id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_contentTemplateItem_ctl00_grdNewsManagement_ctl05_imgbtnDelete | |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | id=ctl00_Dialogproxy_deletenews_btnDelete | |
[error] Element id=ctl00_Dialogproxy_deletenews_btnDelete not found

Actually i am not understanding what is the real issue because manually delete (button) functionality proper run but selenium IDE give the above error

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of the situation in [In Selenium IDE btnDelete (Button) not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788850/in-selenium-ide-btndelete-button-not-found/34793440#34793440)

Judging from the fact you've filed 4 or 5 issues with the same root cause We should assume this is the same issue, though this question could be clearer.