# In Selenium IDE btnDelete (Button) not found

Tags: selenium-ide

Help URL :
URL[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5ZnK.png'
This URL also display a delete button code.

Selenium IDE:
Command        : Target
clickAndWait   : id=ctl00_Dialogproxy_deletenews_btnDelete

Log Table value:
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | id=ctl00_Dialogproxy_deletenews_btnDelete

### [error] Element id=ctl00_Dialogproxy_deletenews_btnDelete not found

Actually i am not understanding what is the real issue because manually delete (button) functionality proper run but selenium IDE give the above error

Comment: is your previous click make popup window appear (in the example you shared in screenshot)?

Comment: This means selenium can not find the element with that id.

Comment: Isn't this a direct duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34760248/in-selenium-ide-btnupdate-not-found-this-is-a-development-code-issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is likely happening is the previous click element launches this "window" with the btnDelete element. So you need to either use a waitFor ( or worse, a pause (don't use pauses).

```
<tr>
<td>waitForElementPresent</td>
<td>id=ctl00_Dialogproxy_deletenews_btnDelete</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is not proper solution, because this command skip the step and directly Jump next step.                                                                           Please give me a proper solution.

Comment: I don't understand your request. Selenium IDE is incapable of "Skipping" steps. Maybe you need to use waitForVisible because the element is already in the dom? Please clarify your answer.