# In Selenium IDE create node text title not found and give the error

Tags: selenium-ide

[Generate error Image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nfPW.png) :
I am also use command and run that i.e. type, typeAndWait, typeKeys, typeKeysAndWait , also give the error

Selenium IDE:

```
Command : Target
type    : id=ctl00_Dialogproxy_deletenews_btnDelete
```

Reference box give the message text :
type(locator, value)
    Arguments:
        locator - an element locator
        value - the value to type
    Sets the value of an input field, as though you typed it in.

### Can also be used to set the value of combo boxes, check boxes, etc. In  these cases, value should be the value of the option selected, not the visible text.

I am send the image URL for all details

Edit: Image was hidden so make it visible.

Comment: When you inspect the element in firefox, do you see Knotenname highlighted if you hover your mouse in `<input id=ctl00_Dialogproxy_deletenews_btnDelete ....`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is again a duplicate of the issue you've noted in [In Selenium IDE btnDelete (Button) not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788850/in-selenium-ide-btndelete-button-not-found/34793440#34793440)

You follow up a "click" that loads a dynamic pop up with an action on a new element. It's possible that selenium is moving to fast for the pop up and the new elements are not in the DOM yet for selenium to access.
I suggest using a "waitFor" action, such as waitForElementPresent. You can also see if this is a case by inserting a pause (with 5 or 10 seconds). I do not recommend pause since it's a hard stop where as a waitFor command will take the minimum amount of time it needs.