# Selenium IDE displays error "Image not found"

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

After clicking on a standard container (Pop-Up window) it does not not open the create container (Pop-up window) window.

[image]

Manually all functionality works properly, but Selenium IDE throws error "Image not found"

Comment: Have you tried `selectWindow/selectPopUp`? See here: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of the issue you posted on [In Selenium IDE btnDelete (Button) not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34788850/in-selenium-ide-btndelete-button-not-found/34793440#34793440)
You have to be careful to follow a click without a waitFor, so that you give the page time to load the new elements.